# comment bar mysql php and ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, apache

I am trying to create a simple comment bar using PHP, AJAX, MySQL and json coding.

I've got two files written in php, the first one being a controller with a following code:

```
<?php
    require("../includes/config.php");
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {

        $comments = query("SELECT comments.comment, comments.author, comments.time FROM comments WHERE workid = ?", $_GET["workid"]);
        echo json_encode($comments);

    }
    else if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_SESSION["userid"])) {
            throw new Exception("Login");
        }
        else {

        $result = query("INSERT INTO comments (comment, author, time, workid) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", $_POST["text"], $_SESSION["userid"], date("Y-m-d H-i-s"), $_POST["workid"]);
        if ($result !== false) {
            echo "success";
        }
        }


    }

?>
```

The second one is purported to display the records from MySQL, based on the data from the controller:

```
<script>
//loads the comments
$(document).ready(function(){
    var comment;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../html/comments.php",
        data: {
            workid: <?php echo $id;?>
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(e) {
            var lis = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
                comment = e[i];
                lis +=

                "<li class='comment'>" + 
                "<div class='well'>" +
                "<p>" + 
                "<a class='username' href='#'>" + comments.author + ": " + "</a>" +
                comments.comment + 


                "</p>" + 

                "<small class='pull-right'>" + comments.time + "</small>" +

                "</div>" + 

                "</li>";



            }
            $("#comments").html(lis);

        },
        error: function(e) {
            $("#comments").html(
                "<li class='comment'> Couldn't load comments </li>"
                );
        }

    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#comment-button").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../html/comments.php",
            data: {
                workid: <?php echo $id;?>,
                text: $("#comment-textarea").val()
            },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(e) {
                var comment;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "../html/comments.php",
                    data: {
                        workid: <?php echo $id;?>
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(e) {
                        var lis = "";
                        for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
                            comment = e[i];

                            lis +=

                            "<li class='comment'>" + 
                            "<div class='well'>" +
                            "<p>" + 
                            "<a class='username' href='#'>" + comments.author + ": " + "</a>" +
                            comments.domment + 


                            "</p>" + 

                            "<small class='pull-right'>" + comments.time + "</small>" +

                            "</div>" + 

                            "</li>";



                        }
                        $("#comments").html(lis);
                        $("#comment-textarea").val("");

                    },
                    error: function(e) {
                        $("#comments").html(
                            "<li class='comment'> Couldn't load comments </li>"
                            );
                    }

                });
            }


        });


});
});
</script>
```

Everything works pretty fine, except of the final step; when displaying the data from the database, the only thing displayed is a statement 'undefined' instead of the corect data. Except of this, the amount of comments and form display correctly. I am using a Apache server with a php installed.

Comment: Is the code meant to be PDO ??

Comment: Yes, it is. PDO is also enabled.

Comment: Could we please have code for method/function query()

Comment: @JakubSedlacek: Did you try my suggestion ? Did it work ?

Comment: -1 for not replying to @ExpertSystem, +1 for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your JavaScript code, you need to replace `comments.<xxx>` with `comment.<xxx>`, since `comments` is indeed an undefined object in your JaveScript.